# GA4 - refunds in Google ads reports

Tags: google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I send Measurment Protocol on purchase and refund.

I created a simple report:
Raw:
Google Ads Campaign
Values:
Google Ads cost
Purchase revenue
Refund amount

Purchase revenue shows only revenue without refunds.
Refund amount total 0

On other reports like source / medium, Refund amount and Purchase revenue works fine (also for Google / CPC).
I connected GA4 to Google Ads.

I need to see Purchase revenue - refunds for Google Ads campaigns.